# Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I want to reject binary which is waiting for review and when I go to the path that [Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) specifies I can't find the button to reject the binary.

Comment: Can you expand somewhat on your question?

Comment: Why would he need to expand? The question is perfectly clear. He wants to reject a binary he submitted, and can't find the button to do so. The button recently got moved from the top right corner of the app version page to an obscure details page.

Comment: It now appears to be in the upper right hand corner of the "Binary Details" page.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

In iTunes connect, from **'My apps'**, select

- Click your application, then
- Make sure you are on the **'Versions'** tab, and that the correct version is selected.
- Click **'Remove this version from review'** located in the info bubble.

See below
[image]

Comment: Having JUST uploaded an incomplete binary (so that I could test StoreKit) I can say clearly that the "reject" link does not show immediately. My status is "Upload received" and has been for 10 minutes, and I still do not have the "reject" link. I am highly assuming it will show up at some point. I will update this thread when that happens.

Comment: EDIT: 
Turns out it took 20 minutes for my binary to go from "received upload" to "waiting for review". I'm sure that time is very subjective. Basically, from what I can tell you cannot reject the binary until it reaches this status.

Comment: @bladnman "Received upload" is the status where iTunes Connect is currently processing your binary. In that state, Apple's servers validate your app (format, icons, folder structure, version number,…). But after a minute (or 20 minutes when their server are heavily loaded) it changes to either "Invalid Binary" (validation failed) or "Waiting for Review" (validation succeeded and now just wait). That's what the iTunes Connect FAQ/Manual says. ;-)

Comment: This appears to have changed now with the re-design of iTunes Connect.. :(

Comment: My app's status is "Waiting for Review" but the info area does not appear.

Comment: Yeah, same with @Siegfoult – the info area does not appear. Was it moved somewhere else?

Comment: I also don't have the bubble, but my version's status is "Waiting For Review", is this a bug?

Comment: To get the blue text box shown above, make some edits to something else on the page (e.g. change the review notes text). Then, the text above will appear.

Comment: No matter what changes I make, my "Waiting for Review" app doesn't let me reject binary.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, our apps are Waiting For Review but iTC doesn't offer a reject facility.  Tried the mobile iTC app trick too but that didn't work either.  Guess we'll have to wait for In Review.

Comment: It took like 20 minutes for that blue bar with the 'reject' button appeared for me, I was super confused at first, but maybe its some weird thing on Apple's end where its in a transitionary state for 20 min or so, then they'll let you cancel it, who knows

Comment: I can confirm for those that want to reject the binary immediately after submitting you have to wait a few minutes and refresh that page for that reject banner to appear.

Answer (score 22):

As a few people have commented/upvoted on @ThomasRS's accepted answer, for whatever reason, even though my app's status was "Waiting for review", the blue bar with the "To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review" message did not appear on the iTunes Connect website on my app's "Waiting for review" version page.

However, I did see a "Reject this binary" link in the iTunes Connect *iOS application*:

[image: iTunes Connect - Product]

Steps to access that page:

1. Open the iTunes Connect app on your iOS device.
2. Sign in with your iTunes credentials when prompted.
3. Open the Products tab (along the bottom).
4. Tap your application.
5. On that screen, tap "Reject This Binary".

Comment: I can not see this link in the iOS app. Care to share a screenshot or at least explain in more detail how to access it?

Comment: @NicolasMiari, added a screenshot and step-by-step directions.

Comment: Thank you. But that button is not being displayed for my app!

Comment: mine did... was quick self reject.

Comment: Its not showing in my iTunes Connect app. I'm using Version 3.1.1(312)

Answer (score 11):

This has all changed with the re-design (as of 12-Sept-2014) you now need to:

> Open the App Details page for the app, as described in To open the App
>   Details page for an app.
>
> On Versions, above the app's metadata, this message appears: "You can
>   only edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To
>   submit a new build, you must remove this version from review." Click
>   "remove this version from review"

[See: Viewing and Changing Your Apps Status and Availability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34)

Comment: thx for your answer. Now I removed binary, app status says developer rejected..but when I upload from organiser then it says redundant binary. How to upload new binary ?

Comment: The only way I could do it was to increase the version number of the build.. You can keep the version number of the app the same but the build must be higher.. Annoying I know..

Comment: yup..even I did same already :) But its really bug in itunesConnect

Comment: What are you using for your numbering convention? Apple ignores zeroes for example..

Comment: I set 2.0 both time. But got error saying redundant binary..finaly set version number to 2.1. and binary approved.

Answer (score 9):

After the changes in iTunesConnect Portal, Here are the new steps:

- Login to iTunes Connect.
- Click on My Apps option.
- Select app for which you want to reject binary.
- Select the version from the left side.
- Reject binary (visible on right side)

[image]
You just need to click on **remove this version from review** (denoted by arrow in above image)

Comment: The "you must remove this version from review" doesn't show up for me, it just skips that part for this version of my current app.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the link to reject appeared after 5-10 minutes after submit, so try to wait 10 minutes.

Comment: This is correct answer. In my case it appears after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I went through the struggle of this as well. I tried everything StackOverflow told me nothing worked. So I did some digging on the site itself and this worked for me.

1. Right click the site in chrome and click "inspect".
2. Click "Elements"
3. Search for "showDevRejectModal".
4. Double click the class parent of this element where it says "ng-modal ng-isolate-scope ng-hide".
5. Delete the "ng-hide".

[image]

Comment: The modal is shown, but after click on **Reject** is raised error about _you can't reject binary in the current state_ (the state is **Waiting for review**).

Answer (score 2):

You may reject your binary at any time.  It will be removed from the review queue and you will go to 'the back of the line' as it were if/when you resubmit your app for review.

From the [Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (log in required):

> When the status of your app is...
>   In Review...you can
>   reject the binary you have submitted
>   by clicking Reject Binary from the
>   Binary Details page...

Comment: However, once the status changes to "in review", it cannot be rejected.

Comment: The reject binary button has been reported to occasionally show as some sort of broken icon or image.  Log out, clear the cache, then restart Safari may do something.

Comment: @S111 - I'm only telling you what is in the guide and what I have personally done myself with my own app submission.

Answer (score 2):

From the new version of iTunes connect, here is what you have to do:

login to iTunes connect. Go to my apps and click on the app for which you wish to reject binary.

In the app details page you will see a particular section, in the Versions tab:

Click on the link 'remove this version from Review'

Once you do that, go to the Build Section of your app - you will see a '-' button when you hower over the mouse above the version number.

Click on the '-' button and your build is removed from the Review Queue.

Pl. note - every build that is removed, will result in further delay to the app- approval time, as your queue position is lost!!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can remove it in Build section.

[image: Versions - Build]

Answer (score 2):

"reject bubble" didn't appear in my case as well. While searching on the web I've found [this](https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs/issues/10) thread which suggested to use the API request below: 
After I've pasted the link in the browser and reload the itunes page, the bubble appeared so I could reject the binary:

```
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/app/[app_id]/versions/[version_id]/reject
```

Make sure to use you app's [app_id] and [version_id] in the request above

Just execute the final request and it should do the trick (pasting the final string with the correct app_id and version_id into your browser's address line should work for this)

Hopefully this option may help someone else.

Comment: @Esquarrouth Still works for me. Make sure to use the correct [app_id] and [version_id] of your app since this is a server API call rather than a plain link. I've edited my answer to indicate the flow in more details

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to Safari from Chrome to see the button

Comment: Same here. The button is hidden in Chrome :/