# How to remove an app that's waiting for review?

Tags: app-store-connect

Because we have discovered and fixed a bug in our app after we uploaded the application to iTunes Connect, we now need to remove the one that has been posted for review and upload the newer version we just built.

Is it possible to do this? There doesn't seem to be any button or link in iTunes Connect to allow us to do this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's called Reject Binary: [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

> In iTunes connect, from **'My apps'**, select
>
> - Click your application, then
> - Make sure you are on the **'Versions'** tab, and that the correct version is selected.
> - Click **'Remove this version from review'** located in the info bubble...

Comment: 'Remove this version from review' will take some minutes to appear.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, but also happened to me. What I did is wait for almost an hour, then change one screenshot, then pressed save. After that the "to submit a build, you must remove this version from review" button appeared.

Comment: Happened to me again haha, I just had to wait for almost an hour and do this trick. Or maybe just a refresh. We just really need to wait :)

Answer (score 2):

You must re upload your original App .zip file as the update, search your trash folder for it. Use the Application launcher and simply re submit the same original zip. When it gets re approved with same original content, only then delete this from Itunes Connect.

Tips:

You cannot delete an app that is Ready For Sale.
You would need to remove your own app from sale before
you can click the Delete button. Find Rights and Pricing button.
You are able to delete your app when it is in one of the following states:

```
Prepare for Upload
Waiting for Upload
Invalid Binary
Developer Rejected
Rejected
Developer Removed from Sale
Removed from Sale
```

I hope this helps.