# how to postpone an iOS app which is " Waiting for review" state

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I got a good name for my future App and named my App.I was too busy that the name has been in itunes connect for nearly more than 180 days. so I have to submit a binary to keep this name for me. And now my iOS app is in " Waiting for review" state, but the Binary is not perfect for review.

What can I do to postpone my App to be reviewed while still keep the App name for me?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just reject binary..............................................................................................................

[Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

Comment: thanks PJR so much for your prompt reply. If I reject my binary, will I be given more grace time for my App name? Can this method bypass the uploading binary within 180 days restriction?

Comment: if you reject your binary then you have to upload it again and it will take same time as before.

Comment: i dont think , it is maximum 15 to 20 days first time too.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Anyway I could have more time to prepare this way.