# Is it possible to re-submit app before it is published?

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, release-management

I submitted an iOS App that has been approved and is ready for release. However I found out a bug that I fixed and hence I haven't published the previously submitted App.

Now I would like to re-sumbit it via AppLoader. Is it possible to do so or do I need to do something on iTunes Connect first?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the apple web store, not about programming.

Comment: Ok... and where can I ask this? The AppDeveloper forum community is slower to reply..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

Comment: The state is not ready for review but simply ready for sale (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your iTunesConnect account.

Click the link to your app.

View Details.

Reject Binary.