# Is it possible to reject the Currently uploaded binary with "In Review" status?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have uploaded an iOS app and it is currently in "In Review" status.
Now I need to make some changes on the build.

How can I reject this binary from review ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You've rejected the binary from the review process, removing it from
>   the review queue.
>
> When you're ready, resubmit your binary or submit a new binary.

Yes you can reject your binary any time it will be removed from review queue . Status of your app will become `Developer Rejected` Read more about it [Here in apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34)

If you have selected manual release mode while submitting, you can even reject it after it's Approved by apple and upload new binary

Here is how you can do it in new iTunes Connect.

- Login to iTunes Connect
- Select app for which you want to reject binary
- reject binary

Here is screenshot of where you can do it in new iTunes connect layout

[image: iTunes Connect image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the option to reject binary in new `iTunes Connect`

[image]

You just need to click on ***remove this version from review*** (denoted by arrow in above image)

Comment: Please check my updated answer and see the arrows in image carefully.