# Reject Binary button missing (remove this version from review)

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

The "remove this version from review" button is missing from itunesconnect. I've seen this post: [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button) but unfortunately the banner is nowhere to be found. Did Apple change that somehow and how can I reject it now?

**Edit**

Here is the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: You can only remove the builds with yellow status . Provide your snapshot under version tab

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did Apple change...??? So Answer is **"NO"**.

Here is screenshoot of my App that is in waiting for review state. I checked it on both Firefox and Safari.

[image]

You can Check This [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34) for more clarification

I just saw the screenshoot you added. No doubt in your case this is a problem. I suggest you to consult with the Apple Developer Support Team.

Comment: Thanks! Just sent an email to the apple support and I am going to let you know how it goes

Comment: I sent them an email and they put it back. I suppose it's a bug on iTunesConnect

Comment: hmmm, yes... Hope no one will face this again :)

Answer (score 6):

I've recently experienced the same issue with iTunes Connect. The blue box didn't appear either on my app's "Versions" tab while it was in "Waiting for Review" status. I emailed Apple, still waiting for a response and had some time to investigate the page's HTML. I found a work around which triggers the reject popup:

Search for "modal for dev reject" in the DOM (it will appear as a comment). Remove the class "ng-hide" from the following DIV.

Comment: I ran into this now but since they changed the CSS I had to search for "tempPageContent.showDevRejectModal" and remove the ng-hide. Worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the source using chrome.

I had to manually hide/unhide the modal:

[image: HIDDEN MODAL]
[image: UNHIDDEN MODAL]

The key phrase to look up is "showDevRejectModal", and delete the "ng-hide" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is log out, wait several minutes and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

just wait for some time (~ 30 mins) and it will show up.

Answer (score -2):

I also experienced this issue. What worked for me is clearing the cache on Safari.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. This should be posted as a comment rather than an answer (when you have sufficient reputation).

Answer (score -3):

Had the exact same problem. Tried submitting a new build, even waited 24 hours, but nothing helped. I also looked in the iTunes Connect app but the "reject binary" button was missing there also.

Eventually I contacted apple support and this is the answer I got:

"Our tools are optimized for Safari. Please try again with a different web browser and let us know if the issue persists."

I then tried with Safari and everything was fine. Strange thing was, it also worked in Chrome (my primary browser) when I tried it after that.

Comment: I tried it with both Safari and Chrome and still nothing

Comment: Actually I think what eventually made it work for me was that I tried editing some random fields and clicking "Save". Suddenly I was able to submit a new build.