# iTunes Connect: Delete app that has been rejected

Tags: app-store-connect

One of our apps was rejected by Apple however I'm unable to delete it from iTunes Connect in order to upload a new version. This post doesn't help: [Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

In iTunes Connect I have:

```
App Review has rejected this app. For more details, see Resolution Center.
```

Here's what I see in iTunes Connect:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to delete it? You can just upload a new binary to the current version to fix the problem.

Comment: @LinusG. Perhaps the iTunes Connect interface has changed recently but I don't see how you upload a new binary.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. **Login** to iTunes Connect
2. Go to **Apps**
3. **Choose** the app you want to edit
4. Scroll down to **Build** as shown in the picture
5. There you can upload the new binary
6. If there is already a build then there should be a little **+** sign right next to the word *Build*

[image: iTunes Connect example for support]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I saw this section so I uploaded the app with Xcode. However, it doesn't then appear here.

Comment: And there isn't a + sign next to the word Build

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues. Apparently you can't reject binaries in this new iTC. Instead in your app under build change it from 1.0 (or whatever it is) to 1.0.1. Then it will override the current build and I guess binary. As for the reason it was rejected they should have emailed you a more detailed explanation and solutions to the reason(s) why it was.