# send message to apple regarding my app uploaded for review on iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I have uploaded my app on iTunes and its status is "Waiting For Review" but I want to send message to apple regarding my uploaded app.I don't get any option to send message to them on iTunes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: It's about app submission to the app store though. It's interesting for some iOS developers.

Comment: @Mikael: That is irrelevant. This question is better suited at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ask different is better suited, indeed. Still, I don't see any problem with this question as there are many other similar questions with accepted answers in here. Do as you wish with the question :) I just want to help the user.

Comment: @Droppy: According to me this question will help the beginner that first time submit the app on iTunes and want to contact apple developer to start reviewing it.as their query regarding app is  successfully answered or delivered.

Comment: @user3587934 According to Apple the role that submits apps to iTunes Connect is the Admin role, not the Developer.  Hence it does not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can eventually cancel your submission

[Reject binary with state waiting for review (can't find reject binary button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button)

and edit your itunes connect page by adding additional remarks in the "Remarks" textfield used by testers when they try your app.

And finally reapply for a new review.

Comment: can i do it without rejecting my binary?actually apple request to send the device for which my app was compatible.so i have delivered that device.so i want to send acknowledgement to apple  that device was successfully delivered.so that they can start reviewing my app as soon as possible.

Comment: If my memory is correct, you might not have access to the review "chat" with the apple reviewer before you get a reject. There is maybe a way but I don't know another one, sorry and good luck.