# Delete app that isn't released yet

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I had an app but the app name has changed and everything. It was just for testing with testflight on itunes connect not released yet. Now how can I delete it?

I don't find any delete button.

Answer (score 0):

To delete your app, you must first reject the build.  After that you will be able to delete your app.

**MORE INFO**

1. Make sure your app has been removed from all countries under the Pricing menu.
2. Once it has been removed the little color dot next to your app icon should be red like this: 
   [image]

Once your dot is red you can delete the app.

Go to the More menu and you will see the Delete App option like this:
[image]

Comment: Where can I reject the build?

Comment: look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34

Comment: I did but I just want to remove it completely that it doesn't show up on itunes connect anymore.

Comment: That's impossible. Why not upload a new build and submit for review?

Comment: once your app has been removed it will allow you to delete it.  See more details in my edit above

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Now It was installed as a free app so thats not the problem. I found this on the apple page: You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of the following. So I think I need to submit my app for review because you need at LEAST one approved version and that I don't have?

Comment: If your app was never reviewed you need to  developer reject the app

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the build. If you have already submit for review,you can [reject it in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915584/reject-binary-with-state-waiting-for-review-cant-find-reject-binary-button). Upload a new build and [choose it in iTunes connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW9),then submit for review. Maybe you want to turn TestFlight Beta Testing off in Prerelease page.

Comment: No what I really want is just to remove it from my itunes connect. It isn't released yet and the concept is changed. The status is waiting for review. But I don't find anything to delete or whatever.

Comment: Actually there is a picture show how you remove the version from review in the first link.

Comment: I know but the app status is 1.0 Developer Rejected so I qualify to delete my app. Now when I click on more I only have the option view on the app store and about this app?